# python script slowing down and almost stops after a couple of seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

I am trying to make a resource monitor with an arduino and it is working great for almost 20 seconds before it almost stops running.
When it slows down, it takes almost 5 seconds between updates.

I have tried to comment out everything with `psuti`l and giving it a permanent value.
and have tried the same with `GPUtil`.

**Here is the python code**

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
import serial
import psutil
import GPUtil
import time
import serial

ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
baud = 9600
for p in ports:
    if "Arduino" in p[1]:
        port = p[0]

ser=serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout=1)
try:
    while True:
        cpuUsage = psutil.cpu_percent()
        ramUsage = psutil.virtual_memory()
        cpuUsage = str(cpuUsage)


        GPUs = GPUtil.getGPUs()
        gpuUsage = GPUs[0].load
        gpuUsage = str(gpuUsage)
        gpuUsage = gpuUsage[2:]

        ramUsage = str(ramUsage.percent)

        toSend = cpuUsage + "," + gpuUsage + ","+ ramUsage
        print (toSend)


        ser.write(toSend.encode())
        #print("20.5".encode())




        #line = ser.readline()[:-2]
        #line.decode()
        #print ("Read : " , line);
        time.sleep(0.1)
except:
    print ("error")
```

**Here is the Arduino code**

```
#include <FastLED.h>
#define NUM_LEDS 15
#define DATA_PIN 6
float Cpu = 40;
float Gpu = 99;
float Ram = 60;
String Cpu_Read;
String Gpu_Read;
String Ram_Read;
int RXLED = 17;
String StrNumbers = "";
int numbers;
int Received = 0;
int Separrator = 0;
String Text = "";
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  FastLED.setBrightness(5);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN_TX,INPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN_RX,INPUT);
}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  char inByte = ' ';
  StrNumbers = "";
  Text = "";
  Separrator = 0;
  Cpu_Read = "";
  Gpu_Read = "";
  Ram_Read = "";
  Received = 0;
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN_TX,INPUT);
  while(Serial.available() > 0){ // only send data back if data has been sent
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN_TX,OUTPUT);
    inByte = Serial.read(); // read the incoming data
    if (inByte == ','){
      Separrator += 1;
    }
    else if (Separrator == 0){
      Cpu_Read +=  (char) inByte;
    }
    else if (Separrator == 1){
      Gpu_Read +=  (char) inByte;
    }
    else if (Separrator == 2){
      Ram_Read +=  (char) inByte;
      Serial.print("Ram : ");
      Serial.println(Ram_Read);
    }
    else{
      Serial.println("Error");
    }
    /*
    inByte = Serial.read(); // read the incoming data
    if (isDigit(inByte)) {  // tests if inByte is a digit
      StrNumbers += (char) inByte;
      Serial.println(inByte); // send the data back in a new line so that it is not all one long line
      //Serial.println(numbers); // send the data back in a new line so that it is not all one long line
    }
    else if (inByte == ".")
    {
      abortLoop = 1;
    }
    else{
      Text +=(char) inByte;
    } 
    */
    Received = 1;
  }
  if (Received == 1){
    Cpu = Cpu_Read.toInt();
    Gpu = Gpu_Read.toInt();
    Ram = Ram_Read.toInt();
    UpdateMonitor(Cpu ,Gpu ,Ram);

  }
  Text.trim();
  if (StrNumbers != ""){
    numbers = StrNumbers.toInt();
    Serial.println(numbers);
    if (numbers > 100) numbers = 100;
    UpdateMonitor(Cpu,numbers,Ram);
  }
  if(Text!= ""){
    //Serial.println(Text); // send the data back in a new line so that it is not all one long line

  }
  if (Text == "ResourceMonitor"){
    Serial.println("Yes");
  }
  else if (Text != ""){
    Serial.println(Text);
    numbers = Text.toInt();
    if (numbers > 100) numbers = 100;
    UpdateMonitor(Cpu, numbers, Ram);
  }



}
void UpdateMonitor(int cpu,int gpu, int ram){
  int Cpu_Usage = map(cpu, 0, 100, 0, 5);
  int Gpu_Usage = map(gpu, 0, 100, 0, 5);
  int Ram_Usage = map(ram, 0, 100, 0, 5);
  FastLED.clear();
  for(int led = 0; led < Ram_Usage; led++) {
    leds[led] = CRGB::Blue;
  }
  for(int led = 0; led < Gpu_Usage; led++) {
    leds[9 - led] = CRGB::Green;
  }
  for(int led = 0; led < Cpu_Usage; led++) {
    leds[led+10] = CRGB::Red;
  }
  FastLED.show();
}
```

Comment: Are you sending too much data for the baud rate? Perhaps you need a sleep after the ser.write

Comment: have a 0.1 sleep at the end and have tried to turn it up to 0.5 but still the sam problem

but have tried turning of the ser.write and then it runs without problems so maybe the problem is on the arduino side?

Comment: So what is on the other side, and which side does the above code run?

Comment: added the arduino code aswell :)

Comment: You must limit the data you send to the baud rate. Can you calculate the minimum sleep needed for the amount of data you send in each ser.write?

Comment: Probably time to start printing everywhere and put the time deltas between each action. Just let it run until the process starts to slow and check where you're loosing most of your time. Does the memory footprint change at all as the script runs?

Comment: the data i am sending is almost none existing i am sending the cpu, gpu, ram usage in percent so 0-100
a data string like this  "28,64,99"
dont know how to calculate that but have tried to use a higher baud rate

Comment: @mccatnm it is stopping at the "ser.write(toSend.encode())"
but dont know if it is because of python or arduino
and the memmory usage on my computer is low

Comment: probably something wrong with the arduino side.
tried starting a game and watched the led output from the arduino and it is updating as it should but when i turned the game of it stoped after a few seconds!
so maybe it is having truble with the low numbers it is getting

Comment: Your data should be sent in about 10ms, so the sleep should be that long, otherwise you will overrun the output buffers. When faced with two devices communicating and both having untested software on them, you need to start simple eg sending a single char (at a limited rate) and prove that you can receive that. Then get progressively more complicated.

Comment: @quamrana i have tried different sleep times without success but now i realised that when the python script is slowing down the arduino is not updating the led strip anymore so the problem is on the arduino side or because they are losing the connection?

Comment: so not because they are losing connection because the the python script should terminate right? because that is what it dose if i unplugg the arduino
but the arduino is not freezing because i just have to restart the python program to get it running again

Answer (score 0):

it is fixed now not sure what fixet it but it works atleast :)
thansk to all that have tried to helt